# My API call throws an error when I use a variable as an argument, but not when I hard code the location into the API call

Tags: javascript, html, async-await, httprequest, weather-api

I am just practicing with API calls and request, by building a simple web app using the Openweatherapi from [Openweather.org](https://openweathermap.org/). It just allows you to type the name of city, and use a button to submit it. The data is fetched, and a description of the city's weather is returned.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Weather App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="cityName">
    <br>
    <button id="citySubmit">Submit city to get weather</button>
   <div id="weatherResponse"></div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
const button = document.getElementById('citySubmit');
const citySearch = document.getElementById('cityName');



const getJSON = async (api) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(api);
      if(!response.ok) // check if response worked (no 404 errors etc...)
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
  
      const data = await response.json(); // get JSON from the response
      return data; // returns a promise, which resolves to this data value
    } catch(error) {
      return error;
    }
}

  /*
  //Call funciton and make http request:

  console.log("Fetching data...");
  getJSON(apiCall).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });*/

  
  console.log("Fetching data...");//Just to see if it's working.
  getJSON(apiCall).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });


  button.addEventListener("click", function(){
//As you can see, Tampa is hard-coded into the API call
    const apiSearch = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=tampa&appid={API Key}';
    console.log("Fetching data...");
    getJSON(apiSearch).then(data => {
        
      const cityName = data.name;
      const country = data.sys.country;
      const description = data.weather[0].description;
      //Weather reponse div
       document.getElementById('weatherResponse').append(`The weather in ${cityName}, ${country} is ${description}.`);
    })/*.catch(error =s> {
      console.error(error);
    });*/
  })
```

As you can see, Tampa is hard-coded into the API call (omitted the key), so when the button is pressed, it will just return Tampa's weather. If the request is done this way it works.

Here is the documentation for call examples:

```
api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}&appid={API key}
```

When I try to make the request by writing it like this, using a variable as an argument that takes the city submitted to the input field: `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+ citySearch +'&appid={API key}` it throws a 404 error.

The API call definitely works as long as the city is hard-coded into the request. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've also used the brackets given in the example but that's probably wrong. Am I using the variable in the API call incorrectly?  I'm stumped.

Comment: `citySearch` is a HTML element

Comment: Maybe you mean `citySearch.value`?

Comment: I added that to the variable in the request and it works!!!!! Thank you! :)